# Deploying React app on Netlify returns 404 page not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, netlify

It deploys successfully, but shows that there are no pages to show. Although the zip file generated has all the data needed.

[image: This is my project layout]

I have my netlify linked with the correct git repo, so I put my base directory to as frontend folder, since I understand that it needs to go there.
[image: Netlify build setings]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish directory should point to directory of your build, i assume that in your case its `build` folder because you are only deploying `/frontend` folder here